# How to add listings or images to the table of contents (TOC)

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a couple of examples (all with titles) and I'd like to create an index/list out of them automatically.

An example can be seen in the [*chunked* AsciiDoc User Guide](https://asciidoc.org/chunked/) table of contents (or beneath):

[image: List of Tables and List of Examples]

The [asciidoc source of the *AsciiDoc User Guide*](https://asciidoc.org/userguide.txt) does not show anything specific to me for Asciidoc itself, I could find the following hint to Docbook:

> DocBook toolchains will normally automatically number examples and generate a 'List of Examples' backmatter section.

I'm looking for the (asciidoctor?) standard html5 rendering, but I'm open for different suggestions.

Adding the `:doctype: book` attribute alone does not do it. So I merely hit dead ends not knowing if it is possible at all. Also I'm new to Asciidoc so I might just miss some pointers, too.

Answer (score 1):

The Python Asciidoc repo includes the `a2x` tool, which is a wrapper around a DocBook toolchain. It is DocBook that is producing these entries in the table of contents. Neither Python Asciidoc, nor `asciidoctor`, can do this out of the box.

You would need to curate the lists manually, or create a macro that does the curation for you. This thread might prove helpful: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/issues/111